# Is Tomcat 5.5.x version compatible with windows 2012 server OS?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-2003-webserver

We are working on Tomcat 5.5.20 on windows 2003 R2x64 bit Server OS.

Now we are going to upgrade our Windows OS from 2003 to 2012. I would like to know whether tomcat 5.5.x version is compatible with windows 2012 server OS. If yes, then which version is compatible and how we proceed with it.

Also confirm JDK & JRE versions working with 2012 windows server.
we are currently using jdk1.5.0_08 and jre1.5.0_08

Thanks In advance

Sachin Jain

Comment: You shouldn't even be asking. You shouldn't be contemplating a brand new deployment of Tomcat 5.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: JDK 1.5 - is it a bank?

Answer (score 0):

The question should be, is jre1.5.0_08 compatible with the windows 2012 server OS because, that is the program that is used to run tomcat?  The [compatibility matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-139801.html) for 1.5 published by Oracle does not list windows server 2012 so therefore it is not "officially" supported.  The [compatibility matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-135212.html) for 1.6 published by Oracle does list windows server 2012.  Using Stefan's [suggestion](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) the minimum version of tomcat that you should use on Windows Server 2012 is therefore Tomcat 7.  Of course, the [compatibility matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-139801.html) for 1.4 published by Oracle does not list windows server 2012 - I mention this because that JRE is probably used by a lot of other installations that still use Tomcat 5.

Update based on Dave's comment:

- Dave is quite correct.  You can run any version of tomcat up to version 7 on java 6, which is the minimum **java** version that can be used with windows 2012.

Comment: That Tomcat chart goes the other direction; Tomcat 7 requires Java 6 or later, but Java 6 can run earlier Tomcat. It may well be desirable for other reasons to move to newer and actively supported Tomcat, but it isn't necessary because of newer Java.